# Change Javascript generated SVG icon

Tags: javascript

I am duplicating this Navigation menu on this site https://www.rolls-roycemotorcars.com/en_US/home.html.

Everything works but I can't change the burger icon from 3 lines to 2 lines. I know the burger icon is being generated in the Main Componet JS file. But everytime I edit the JS code nothing is changing or breaks.

**JS** and **CSS** files:

```
[CSS][1]
[Jquery][2]
[Utility JS][3]
[Main Componet JS][4]

[1]: https://bespokecompani.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/divi-child/css/clientlib-components.c72b4bbd09d843175dff767d1db82ed4.css
[2]: https://bespokecompani.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/divi-child/js/jquery.0811b5e7037ada110b591bbd86240386.js
[3]: https://bespokecompani.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/divi-child/js/utils.7d1c4e1c54f4b3bce718f5d6a06ffd06.js
[4]: https://bespokecompani.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/divi-child/js/clientlib-components.e9aeefa073ccbafcfb535d6b58a1e91b.js
```

I had to add the files as links because they have 20,000 + lines of code

Any help would be great

Comment: Sorry, but you expect us to read *"20,000 + lines of code"* to find the problem?
Please, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

A simple change from line to cross can be done with the before and after [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). Then (in this case via hover) you can change their styling so it becomes a cross. Down below is the same example but with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

```css
/* Styling for the button */
.menu-button {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

/* Styling for each line */
.menu-button span,
.menu-button span::before,
.menu-button span::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
}

/* Center line transitions */
.menu-button span {
  display: block;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

/* Top/bottom line transitions */
.menu-button span::before,
.menu-button span::after {
  content: "";
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

/* Offset top line */
.menu-button span::before {
  transform: translateY(-1rem);
}

/* Offset bottom line */
.menu-button span::after {
  transform: translateY(calc(1rem - 3px)); /* we use calc to make sure the line is wihtin the button */
}

/* On hover: hide center line */
.menu-button:hover span {
  background: none;
}

/* On hover: translate and rotate top line */
.menu-button:hover span:before {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* On hover: translate and rotate bottom line */
.menu-button:hover span:after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" aria-label="Toggle menu" class="menu-button">
  <span></span>
</button>
```

**Bonus with CSS variables:**

```css
/* Styling for the button */
.menu-button {
  --btn-size: 2rem;
  --line-height: 3px;
  --line-color: black;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  width: var(--btn-size);
  height: var(--btn-size);
}

/* Styling for each line */
.menu-button span,
.menu-button span::before,
.menu-button span::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: var(--line-color);
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--line-height);
}

/* Center line transitions */
.menu-button span {
  display: block;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

/* Top/bottom line transitions */
.menu-button span::before,
.menu-button span::after {
  content: "";
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

/* Offset top line */
.menu-button span::before {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--btn-size) / 2 * -1));
}

/* Offset bottom line */
.menu-button span::after {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--btn-size) / 2) - var(--line-height)));
}

/* On hover: hide center line */
.menu-button:hover span {
  background: none;
}

/* On hover: translate and rotate top line */
.menu-button:hover span:before {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* On hover: translate and rotate bottom line */
.menu-button:hover span:after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<p>You can change `--btn-size`, `--line-height` and `--line-color` in CSS and watch the button change</p>

<button type="button" aria-label="Toggle menu" class="menu-button">
  <span></span>
</button>
```